# Dual photo transistor component reference (like used in old mechanical mouses)

Tags: identification, components, phototransistor, mechanical, mouse

Context : I'm trying to implement a way to detect the rotation speed of a motor (no problem) and also get it's direction.
I know all the basics, don't worry :) (placement difference between 2 photo transistors permitting to get the direction etc)

To do my things, I salvaged some old mechanical mouses, took the "rotation wheels" (technically, they are no coding wheels as there is no code in there) also took the IR diode, and most importantly the photo transistors.

These photo transistors got 3 pins, in the middle the supply voltage and on each end the signal pins for each photo transistor. Easy, very nice.
The 2 photo transistors in there are separated by a very small distance, which is realy great and induce the need of only 1 component easy to install

Problem : I'd like to be able to buy some brand new ***DUAL*** photo receivers like the ones described before...
But I can't find any reference. I tryed Farnell, radiospares, aliexpress, a lot of key words, but no success.
Some of the photo transistors I salvaged got some references on them, but this leads to nothing (real nothing, not even one result)

Maybe there is a specific name (which I don't know) that would give me lots of results?
Edit : I really search for the ***DUAL*** ones, not SINGLE. of what I saw until now, 99.9% are single channel :'(

Please, point me to a component I can actually buy :)

Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a small break on the subject, I went back on searching, and found something that might be interesting (at least in my case)
Here is the full list of Dual channel photo receivers / slotted Optocouplers / opto switch I achieved to find :

ASTS150 250 832S 832SD 822S 822SD (Unavailable)

SITAB74 (Unavailable)

OBP822S/SD OBP826S/SD (5€ / 1p)

HEDS-9730 HEDS-9731 (2.8€ / 1p)

TCUT1600X01 (10€ / 5p) (5.5 * 4 * 5.7 mm)

TCUT1350X01 (?) (5.5 * 4 * 4 mm)(more powerful diode?)

TCUT1300X01 (6.71€ / 10) (5.5 * 4 * 4 mm)

In my case, the **TCUT1300X01** will be the one interesting as it's small and not too much expensive :)

Thanks for the help people :)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for [slotted+opto+switch+dual+channel](https://www.google.com/search?q=slotted+opto+switch+dual+channel&tbm=isch) throws up many results including, for example, the [OPB826](https://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/344/OPB826-pdf.php).

Comment: Thanks, this helps a bit. But, in fact, I'm looking for a 3 pined component (not 4 as in the ones you said about), and just the receiver, not the full package (already got IR diodes very nice to be implemented in my stuff). Got any idea / lead?

Answer (score 0):

These are called "photo interrupters".

Once you find that category at the supplier, search for the 3-pin ones (they are fairly common)

[EXAMPLE #1](https://www.arrow.com/en/categories/optoelectronics/photoelement/photointerrupters)

[EXAMPLE #2](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/omron-automation-and-safety/EE-SPX306-W2A/368589)

If you want just the receiving side, it is called a "phototransistor".

[EXAMPLE](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/vishay-semiconductor-opto-division/BPW76A/1681152)

Comment: Thanks for the "photo interrupters" term :) . I knew phototransistors, already searched that. But the problem is that they are all (99.9%) SINGLE channel, and I'm looking for a DUAL channel... Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for optical encoder and you'll find some which are quadrature pickups sans code wheel. For example, the Broadcom/Avago HEDS-9730 (image below from datasheet).

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I already searched ith these key words without real success. The most part of results consist of integrated optical encoders with a shaft you have to turn to get the signal... Seeing the prices of photo interrupters (about 5€ per part), i'll probably go for this kind, bu it's not optimal for what I want to do :'( Anyway, thanks for the help !